# mysqli_set_charset() Serbian letters won't appear in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

when I insert data into mysql database Serbian letter like č looks like Ä and ć looks like Ä‡.
In header I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and encoding is set to utf8_unicode_ci so I don't know where is the problem...

When I put

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
```

before insert, then in mysql is looking good, but in my app ć is appear as symbol ?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Mario `utf8_unicode_ci` would suffice. As for Shone83, please provide a [mcve] because we cannot verify.

Comment: Set collation and column collation to `utf8_bin` and remove this line of code `mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");` This is working for me on localhost and on live server for ćčšžđ.

Comment: I try to set to utf8_bin, check Change all column collations and delete code but the result are the same...

Comment: Do you maybe have some function to insert data into database ?

Comment: No, just like this:

$query = "INSERT INTO anketa(ime, prezime, jmbg, telefon1, telefon2, email) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('{$ime}', '{$prezime}', '{$jmbg}', '{$telefon1}', '{$telefon2}', '{$email}')";

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored